DMI as a Superexchange?
Superexchnage interaction is an indirect exchange interaction between two magnetic ions; Anderson proposed a model that says the origin of this type of exchange is due to the arrangement of Molecular orbitals as summarised by GKA rules, which favours Antiferromagnetic or ferromagnetic coupling depending on the bond angle. The DMI interaction can be explained as a superexchange interaction when Spin-orbit coupling is taken into the calculation where a lack of inversion symmetry is needed to induce such exchange. My question is, Can someone prove all this theoretically?

Consider to spell out acronyms.

Moriya's 1960 paper is quite readable. See also Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_exchange
